# How can i use Bitcoin payment method through Swift for my IOS Project?

Tags: payment, ios

I am trying to create **Bitcoin Payment** in my **IOS** project. I'm using swift language. I search this topic in lots of sites, youtube, stack overflow. but i just getting HTTP request related topics. Any one have solution? Ping me...

Answer (score 2):

[Core Bitcoin](https://github.com/oleganza/CoreBitcoin) is a library for iOS written in Objective-C.  I have worked with it in Swift using the bridging header.

I myself have written a few Swift [classes](https://github.com/doffing81/iOS_Swift_DescartesWallet), in my experimental/educational wallet, for creating addresses, keys, and transactions, but I wouldn't recommend using it for anything.  Feel free to take a look and see if you find anything interesting, or anything that you could learn from.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use BitPay's payment API, using Swift's URLRequest. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24016254/6557621) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27814347/6557621) for Swift documentation, and [this webpage](https://bitpay.com/api) for BitPay API documentation.

Please note that if your app uses Bitcoin payment system [your app may not be liked by Apple](https://www.recode.net/2016/6/30/12067578/spotify-apple-app-store-rejection).

Answer (score 0):

[BitcoinKit](https://github.com/horizontalsystems/bitcoin-kit-ios) is a Swift SDK proposing a Bitcoin wallet implementation. This is a full implementation of SPV node including wallet `creation`, `restore`, `synchro with network`, `sending` and `receiving` transactions, etc. Also, look at BitcoinKit on [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/BitcoinKit).

[image]

Here's a code snippet showing how it looks like:

```
import UIKit
import BitcoinKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet private weak var qrCodeImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet private weak var addressLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var balanceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var destinationAddressTextField: UITextField!    
    private var wallet: Wallet? = Wallet()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.createWalletIfNeeded()
        self.updateLabels()
    }
    
    func createWalletIfNeeded() {
        if wallet == nil {
            let privateKey = PrivateKey(network: .testnetBCH)
            wallet = Wallet(privateKey: privateKey)
            wallet?.save()
        }
    }
    
    func updateLabels() {
        qrCodeImageView.image = wallet?.address.qrImage()
        addressLabel.text = wallet?.address.cashaddr
        if let balance = wallet?.balance() {
            balanceLabel.text = "Balance : \(balance) satoshi"
        }
    }
    
    func updateBalance() {
        wallet?.reloadBalance(completion: { [weak self] (utxos) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async { self?.updateLabels() }
        })
    }

    @IBAction func didTapReloadBalanceButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        updateBalance()
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapSendButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let addressString = destinationAddressTextField.text
        else { return }
        
        do {
            let address: BitcoinAddress = try AddressFactory.create(addressString)
            try wallet?.send(to: address, amount: 10000, completion: { [weak self] (response) in
                print(response ?? "")
                self?.updateBalance()
            })
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```